# Laravel echo a var in a string or in DB

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a string like this

```
<tr><td>{{ $name }}</td><td>{{ $number }}</td></tr>
```

and I echo it in a blade template.

In controller I `return view('test',compact('name','number'))`.

But it is outputting like this

```
{{ $name }} {{ $number }}
```

How to get the value of `$name` and `$number`.

Comment: Are you sure you have file with extension `.blade.php` instead of `.php`

Comment: in your view .. `filename.blade.php` instead of `filename.php`

Answer (score 0):

At the controller make your variables.

```
public function myAction()
{
    $number = 12 * 5;

    return view('test', [
        'name' => 'My name',
        'number' => $number,
    ]);
}
```

And then you can get these variables by calling in blade:

`{{ $name }}` - shows 'My name'.

`{{ $number }}` - shows number 60.

Comment: Tks i did it but my string after i put just show me the same in my test view i have another var is $text it is my string, i ajax to test view so laravel just know it is text and print it